# JQuery - Run either window resize or orientation change.

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function that I need to run in order to re-position my slider.

This has to happen when the window is resized or if the device orientation is changed. It can't fire twice as it causes all sorts of issues.

The issue I have is with the following code resize & orientation both trigger on orientation change so I need a way to detect one and not use the other but i'm just unsure on how to really go about it.

```js
function cssliderOrientation(trigger){

        setTimeout(function() {
        
        $( "<p>" + trigger + "</p>" ).appendTo( ".container" );
        
        }, 1000);
}

$( window ).on( "orientationchange", function() {
        cssliderOrientation('orientationChange');
    });
    
    $(window).resize(function() {
        cssliderOrientation('Resize');
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container"></div>
```

Comment: isn't the "resize" event being fired on orientation change?

Comment: @StefanGabos yes that is the issue.

Answer (score 1):

The double firing of the function happens when both statements are true.

- You change the orientation.
- The event "orientationchange" gets triggered.
- The event "resize" gets triggered

Orientation changing causes the screen to resize already and therefore triggering the event. So the first event can be left out in this case.

Comment: This isn't and answer mate.

Comment: It is, it means you are not using the event handlers properly. But if you really want to hack around it you could always write your own event manually checking for your own conditions to fire.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events

Comment: No it is not. You just explained what orientationchange & resize do.... Obviously well aware of why it's happening. What The question was if there is a way to detect orientationchange and stop resize from working.......

Comment: While it doesn't _solve_ your problem 100% (you cannot copy/paste from the answer), I believe that the answer gives a lot of insight into why the issue is happening, and is hence helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a variabale to check if the function has already been called. If it has the `cssliderOrientation` function call will return. And after the timeout function call you just set the variable back to false.

```
var onSliderOrientation = false;
function cssliderOrientation(trigger){
       if(onSliderOrientation){
           return;
       }

       onSliderOrientation = true;

       setTimeout(function() {

          $( "<p>" + trigger + "</p>" ).appendTo( ".container" );
          onSliderOrientation = false;

        }, 1000);
}

$( window ).on( "orientationchange", function() {
        cssliderOrientation('orientationChange');
    });

    $(window).resize(function() {
        cssliderOrientation('Resize');
    });
```

The issue with this is that the second time `cssliderOrientation` is called, if the call happens after the timeout of the first call expired, it will be called twice either way. In your case it may not be a problem but just be aware that I am not a big fan of this kind of solutions.

Comment: I had actually attempted this approach by running an if statement within the revise if the variable was true not to run it but had no luck